# Auto-Completion in iPhone SDK 3.2

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, xcode3.2

I installed the iPhone SDK 3.2 in my mac mini. my problem is, i am using UITableview* i want to get the properties of the tableview i.e, when i am typing tableview. and press escape i have to get the corresponding values instead i am getting "No Completions found" if i am typing the wanted property and build i am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for autocompletions **[UITableview ...]** where ... is where you type.
Xcode will only autocompletes on method calls and properties, as well as when you start typing the class type for a declaration. However the class name itself is up to you.

So in your example **UITableView* ...** it cannot autocomplete because it is up to you to declare the instance name (although a mind reading autocomplete would be nice sometimes!)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the place for that question. The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) writes:

> If your question is about […] general
>   computer software or hardware
>   troubleshooting, ask on [Super
>   User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: how is this an iphone programming question? he's asking how to fix a problem with the xcode environment, not with the sdk or with any specific code.